# how to run vmware 12.5.1 on ubuntu 17.10 (not working)

Tags: 16.04, kernel, 17.10, vmware

i'll install vmware 12.0 but it is not working.

[image]

log file details

```
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=30222 version=12.5.1 build=build-4542065 option=Release
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Host is Linux 4.10.0-40-generic 
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/virajlinux/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/virajlinux/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/virajlinux/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.454+05:30| vthread-4| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-30222.log
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:52.471+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.471+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:52.681+05:30| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-05T21:42:52.681+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Read 21375 symbol versions
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.706+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.706+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.707+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.707+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.709+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.709+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.710+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.710+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.711+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.726+05:30| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2018-01-05T21:42:52.726+05:30| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2018-01-05T21:42:52.744+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.744+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.744+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.744+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:52.750+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.750+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:52.987+05:30| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-05T21:42:52.987+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Read 21375 symbol versions
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:53.028+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.028+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:53.029+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2018-01-05T21:42:53.032+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.032+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.032+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.035+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.035+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:53.046+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.046+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:53.047+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.047+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.047+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:53.071+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.071+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:53.071+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.077+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.077+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.077+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.077+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:53.083+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.084+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:53.312+05:30| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-05T21:42:53.312+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.347+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Read 21375 symbol versions
2018-01-05T21:42:53.347+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.349+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.349+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.351+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.870+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.870+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.879+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.879+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-f2V5NG/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-01-05T21:42:56.129+05:30| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2018-01-05T21:42:56.131+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2018-01-05T21:42:56.131+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2018-01-05T21:42:56.136+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2018-01-05T21:42:56.136+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-f2V5NG/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-01-05T21:42:58.370+05:30| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

plz hlp me....
i'll try to install kernel but it is not work

Comment: What does the logfile mentioned in the error message say ? Please update your question with the content of this file.

Comment: i'll try to install kernel but i can not understand it?

Comment: I suggest you run vmware on a supported host or use an alternate such as KVM or Virtualbox

Comment: yes Virtualbox is installed

Comment: now i'll uninstall it

Comment: i'll try vmware player 14 it is work but 12 is not work

Comment: The older versions of VMWare often do not compile properly in the new kernels without patches - this becomes a problem that you should research at the VMWare community forums.  If you seach this site for "Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command." you will find that this happens about every major release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Please see the VMWare forums at [https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/workstation](https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/workstation)

Comment: ok. how can i install old kernel? it is work or not